# How to lift up to disappear a popup window after long click to show?

Tags: android

I have a view(ImageView in a list, not big actually) which has a longClick listener registered for triggering a popup up window. And I want popup to disappear after it shows when I lift up my finger from the screen.

For clear statement, I show some of my code:

A longClick listener to the view:

```
public void onPopup(View view){
     // New a popup and show it
}
```

And I tried setting a onTouch listener on the both view and its parent or root specifically.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
             switch(event.getAction()){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                          mPopup.dismiss();
             }
             return false; // If true here, the long click listener won't work anymore
     }});
```

The code works when I trigger the popup and lift up finger, the popup dismisses, that's to say, it just involves ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP(I logged the events afterwards).

However, the problem occurs when I make some move events between the DOWN and UP events. Exactly, the popup shows, then I move my finger a little bit or scroll (the finger does not leave the screen). Finally, I lift up my finger, the popup does not dismiss at all.

I logged the three events to test it, and found that the DOWN event that triggers the popup is fine, and whatever the next event is UP or DOWN is logged, means they could be caught. But after logged the MOVE events(like a few second), nothing event occurs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this is happening is because you need to tell the system if you have or haven't used the event, and you need to calculate how long they have pressed down for. So by implementing it like this, it will work.

```
private AlertDialog dialog;

private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchClickListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private static final int CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD = 500;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                hidePopup();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showPopup();
        }
    };
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHelloWorld);

    view.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchClickListener);
}

private void showPopup() {
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("hello").create();
    dialog.show();
}

private void hidePopup() {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

The `CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD` being how long you want them to have to press down for.

Comment: But I want it to show when long click, not just one ACTION_DOWN which means click

Comment: This is more clear. But, it still failed to dismiss. When I just move a little bit after it shows, it doesn't go away anymore

Comment: Hmm that is weird, for me it is fine. I press down, move my finger, (popup appears), move my finger again and then release (popup disappears). Are you implementing exactly what I've done? And have I correctly understood what you want?

Comment: Let I put it straight, I logged three event. I am for sure Action_Down reached(the moment I clicked) at first, and second event could be printed properly on the console(ACTION_UP OR MOVE), afterwards nothing logged in console anymore, whatever I do later. Or to say, there's no third event.

Comment: Nothing printed on console means I think the view isn't able to catch the event. Anyway, thanks for the insightful reply, I think the problem is the something messes up with my other layout, the image view is embedded in the recycler view in a view pager.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I couldn't be any more help!